# GUI plot refreshing incorrectly on wxpython panel

Tags: user-interface, plot, wxpython, refresh

Ok, so I've been tasked with creating a VERY simple GUI at work (I'm an intern). The task is to eventually connect to a machine and process real data, but right now I'm working on randomly generated sine data with noise. I've chose to work in Python 3.0, and use wxpython to create my GUI components.

As I want everything to appear on the same window, I'm using panels (hence wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas rather than something like matplotlib.pyplot)

The problem that I have is that over time, the plot seems to 'expand' off of the panel. This is temporarily solved when I manually resize the window, but resumes again immediately after (you need to run the code to see what I mean).

[Expansion over time in panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vakWs.jpg)

Another problem (that has bugged me since I have started writing the code) is that sometimes when I resize the window (manually) or minimize it and then maximize it again, the timer randomly starts and stops.

I have tried all sorts of things (changing padding in sizers, extra arguments, changing time between refreshes GetBestSize()) but I believe that I simply don't understand wxpython well enough to identify where the problem is
I would really appreciate any help you can shed on either of these problems (I don't know, they might even be linked to each other).

FYI: I am not an experienced coder, and my code is not finished (I have more functions to code, but I feel like I should resolve this first). I have constructed this code by looking at different techniques from various tutorials and websites like stackoverflow, so I know it's not formatted well and could definitely be made more efficient. Also, I have removed some parts just to be safe about confidentiality - nothing important, just strings in messages.

PS: If you do have an easier way to do the whole plot/update thing that doesn't have this problem (preferably still in wx) I would be thrilled to hear that as well

And here's my code:

EDIT: Solved the expanding problem by using self.p2.SetSize((W+0,L+0)) instead of (self.p2.GetBestSize())

EDIT: Made transitions much smoother by just regenerating data and redrawing it on existing canvas in the evt_timer function (instead of recreating the whole canvas, which gave a blink-y appearance if you know what I mean)

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import wx.lib.plot as plot
import time
import os

wildcard =  "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|"\
            "Picture (*.png)|*.png|"\
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"#This wildcard shows the options for file endings in the "SAVE" tab - see OnSave(self,event)

wildcard2 = "Picture (*.png)|*.png|"\
            "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|"\
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"

class PlotCanvas(plot.PlotCanvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,size,accepted):
        """
        This randomly generates sine data (with noise) and plots it to a panel.
        Incorporated as a separate class instead of instatiating it as a plot.PlotCanvas object 
        to overcome an issue of the size of the plot in the panel.
        """
        plot.PlotCanvas.__init__(self,parent,id,style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN,size = size)
        N = 100 # number of data points
        self.t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
        f = 1.15247 # Optional!! Advised not to use
        self.data = 3.0*np.sin(f*self.t+0.001) + 0.5 + np.random.randn(N) # create artificial data with noise        
        guess_mean = np.mean(self.data)
        guess_phase = 0
        guess_freq = 1
        guess_amp = 1        
        optimize_func = lambda x: x[0]*np.sin(x[1]*self.t+x[2]) + x[3] - self.data
        est_amp, est_freq, est_phase, est_mean = leastsq(optimize_func, [guess_amp, guess_freq, guess_phase, guess_mean])[0]  
        fine_t = np.arange(0,max(self.t),0.1)
        data_fit=est_amp*np.sin(est_freq*fine_t+est_phase)+est_mean

        multiplier = 1


        dataset1 = [(x,[d for d in self.data][[td for td in self.t].index(x)])for x in [td for td in self.t]]
        fitdata1 = [(x,[df for df in data_fit][[tf for tf in fine_t].index(x)]) for x in [tf for tf in fine_t]]
        dataset =[(x,y*multiplier) for (x,y) in dataset1]
        fitdata = [(x,y*multiplier) for (x,y) in fitdata1]
        self.data = dataset
        self.data2 = fitdata
        line = plot.PolyLine(self.data,legend = 'random',colour = 'light blue', width =2)
        line2 = plot.PolyLine(self.data2,legend = 'sineline',colour ='black',width =2)
        a = []
        if "D" in accepted:
            a.append(line)
        if "S" in accepted:
            a.append(line2)
        if "G" in accepted:
            pass
        if "L" in accepted:
            pass
        gc = plot.PlotGraphics(a,'Line Graph','X','Y')
        xmin = self.t[0]-0.01*(self.t[-1]-self.t[0])
        xmax = self.t[-1]+0.01*(self.t[-1]-self.t[0])
        self.Draw(gc,xAxis=(xmin,xmax),yAxis=(min([x[1] for x in dataset])-0.01*(max([x[1] for x in dataset])-min([x[1] for x in dataset])),
                            max([x[1] for x in dataset])+0.01*(max([x[1] for x in dataset])-min([x[1] for x in dataset]))))
        #self.showLegend = True
        #self.enableZoom = True
    def Dialog(self, parent, message, c):# Will be used to notify the user of errors/processes
        if c == "W":
            caption = "Warning!"
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, message, caption, wx.OK | wx.ICON_WARNING)
        elif c == "I":
            caption = "Information"
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, message, caption, wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()#Destroys dialog on close

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    """
    This is the main class. In it, we declare the separate panels, canvas, menubar, buttons and sizers.

    """
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition)
        self.CurrentDirectory = os.getcwd()
        self.timer=wx.Timer(self)#Instantiating the timer
        self.count=0
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.evt_timer)#Binding it to itself so that it is always triggered
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.paint)

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        fileMenu = wx.Menu() #Creating the Menubar at the top

        #Creating 3 menus: fileMenu,fit,and help

        save = wx.Menu()
        z = wx.MenuItem(save,wx.ID_ANY,'Save Raw Data\tCtrl+D')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnSave,z)
        save.Append(z)

        z= wx.MenuItem(save,wx.ID_ANY,'Save Image\tCtrl+I')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnSaveImage,z)
        save.Append(z)

        fileMenu.AppendSubMenu(save,'&Save')

        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

        z = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit\tCtrl+W')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, z)
        fileMenu.Append(z)

        fit = wx.Menu()#Making a check menu
        self.gaussian = fit.Append(wx.ID_ANY,'Gaussian',kind = wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.ToggleGaussian,self.gaussian)
        fit.Check(self.gaussian.GetId(),False)

        self.sine = fit.Append(wx.ID_ANY,'Sine',kind = wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.ToggleSine,self.sine)
        fit.Check(self.sine.GetId(),False)

        self.linear = fit.Append(wx.ID_ANY,'Linear',kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.ToggleLinear,self.linear)
        fit.Check(self.linear.GetId(),False)




        help = wx.Menu()
        z = wx.MenuItem(help,wx.ID_ANY,'&About\tCtrl+H')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,self.OnHelp,z)
        help.Append(z)

        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        menubar.Append(fit, '&Fit')
        menubar.Append(help, '&Help')#adding menus to menubar 

        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)#formatting the frame with menubar

        self.sp = wx.SplitterWindow(self)#Splitting the window into 2 panels
        self.p1 = wx.Panel(self.sp,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)#For buttons and user events
        self.p2 = wx.Panel(self.sp,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)#For display of the plot
        self.sp.SplitVertically(self.p1,self.p2,300)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(3, 3)#Versatile sizer for layout of first panel self.p1
        bitmappath = self.CurrentDirectory + "\\BITMAPS"

        bmp = wx.Bitmap(bitmappath+"\\SAVE.BMP",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
        self.saveBtn = wx.BitmapButton(self.p1,wx.ID_ANY,bitmap = bmp,size =(bmp.GetWidth()+10,bmp.GetHeight()+10))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnSave,self.saveBtn)
        sizer.Add(self.saveBtn, (0, 0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.ALL,5)

        bmp = wx.Bitmap(bitmappath +"\\START.BMP",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
        self.startBtn = wx.BitmapButton(self.p1,-1,bitmap = bmp,size =(bmp.GetWidth()+10,bmp.GetHeight()+10))# A button that starts and stops the plotting
        self.startBtn.startval = "START"
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.paint,self.startBtn)
        sizer.Add(self.startBtn, (0, 1), wx.DefaultSpan,wx.ALL,5)





        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        W,L = self.p2.GetSize()
        self.p2.canvas = PlotCanvas(self.p2,wx.ID_ANY,(W,L),["D"])

        sizer1.Add(self.p2.canvas,1,wx.ALL,0,0)
        self.p2.SetSizerAndFit(sizer1)




        self.p1.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.p2.SetSizerAndFit(sizer1)
        self.p2.SetSize(W,L)
        self.Maximize(True)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        ############### event  methods ###########
    def paint(self,event):
        """
        Updates the canvas based on the value of the startbtn(not the image). Bound to self.timer.
        """
        bitmappath = self.CurrentDirectory + "\\BITMAPS"
        if self.startBtn.startval == "START":
            self.timer.Start(1)# increase the value for more time
            bmp = wx.Bitmap(bitmappath + "\\STOP.BMP",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
            self.startBtn.SetBitmap(bmp)
            self.startBtn.startval = "STOP"
        elif self.startBtn.startval == "STOP":
            self.timer.Stop()
            bmp = wx.Bitmap(bitmappath+ "\\START.BMP",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
            self.startBtn.SetBitmap(bmp)
            self.startBtn.startval = "START"
    def evt_timer(self,event):
        self.count +=1
        if self.count== 10:# By increasing count (or the number in self.timer.Start()) you can increase the interval between updates
            #self.p2.canvas.Clear()
            sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            W,L = self.p2.GetSize()
            a = ["D"]
            if self.sine.IsChecked():
                a.append("S")
            elif self.linear.IsChecked():
                a.append("L")
            elif self.gaussian.IsChecked():
                a.append("G")
            self.p2.canvas = PlotCanvas(self.p2,wx.ID_ANY,(W,L),a)
            sizer1.Add(self.p2.canvas,1,wx.ALL,0,0)
            self.p2.SetSizerAndFit(sizer1)
            self.p2.SetSize(self.p2.GetBestSize())
            self.count=0 # reset the count
    def Dialog(self, parent, message, c):# Will be used to notify the user of errors/processes
        if c == "W":
            caption = "Warning!"
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, message, caption, wx.OK | wx.ICON_WARNING)
        elif c == "I":
            caption = "Information"
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, message, caption, wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()#Destroys dialog on close
    def OnSave(self,event):#Triggered by menubar and button
        try:
            rawdata = self.p2.canvas.data
            raw_X =[x[0] for x in rawdata]
            raw_Y =[x[1] for x in rawdata]

            dlg = wx.FileDialog(#Code for this from http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org
                self, message="Save file as ...", 
                defaultDir=self.CurrentDirectory, 
                defaultFile=str(time.ctime()), wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.FD_SAVE
                )
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                path = dlg.GetPath()
            dlg.Destroy()

            f = open(path+".txt","w+")

            for i in range(len(raw_X)):
                f.write(str(raw_X[i])+"\t"+str(raw_Y[i])+"\n")
            f.close()
            self.Dialog(None,"File successfully saved","I")
        except UnboundLocalError:#Catch error when user closes save window without selecting any directory or filename
            pass
    def OnSaveImage(self,event):
        try:
            rawdata = self.p2.canvas.data
            raw_X = [x[0] for x in rawdata]
            raw_Y = [x[1] for x in rawdata]
            dlg = wx.FileDialog(
                self, message="Save file as ...", 
                defaultDir=self.CurrentDirectory, 
                defaultFile=str(time.ctime()), wildcard=wildcard2, style=wx.FD_SAVE
                )
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                path = dlg.GetPath()
            dlg.Destroy()
            fig1 = plt.figure()

            plt.plot(raw_X,raw_Y)
            plt.title("Raw Data")
            fig1.savefig(path+".png")
            self.Dialog(None,"File successfully saved","I")
        except UnboundLocalError:
            pass
    def OnMultiply(self,e):
        try:
            factor = self.x.GetValue()
            factor = float(factor)
            self.IntegrationTime = factor

        except ValueError as e:
            self.Dialog(None,str(e),"W")

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()
    def OnHelp(self,e):
        self.Dialog(None,"N/A","I")
    def ToggleSine(self,e):
        pass
    def ToggleLinear(self,e):
        self.Dialog(None,"Not added yet","W")
    def ToggleGaussian(self,e):
        self.Dialog(None,"Not added yet","W")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app=wx.App()
    Frame(None,-1,"N/A")
    app.MainLoop()
```